# Split payment for subscriptions on Stripe platform account

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

The [stripe api documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api) doesn't seem to cover a specific case I'm looking for:

*Subscribe someone to a plan on the platform account, and automatically send a portion of their monthly dues to a second account*:

I have two accounts:

- Platform
- Service

I have a plan, `platformplan` on the Platform account.

I want to subscribe someone to that plan, but send a portion of that cost to the Service account.

---

A similar, but not applicable request is covered by their documentation:

A `serviceplan` on the Service account can be [subscribed to and an application fee taken](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#collecting-fees-on-subscriptions) via:

```
application_fee_percent: 10,
stripe_account: "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
```

This works (and very helpfully shows the Service account the fee breakdown and total cost), but requires I have access to the Service account if I want to change the plans, which is not ideal. I am trying to set it up so I can have separate plans on the platform (which I control) connected to payable service accounts.

---

You can split a [charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object) via the [destination](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-destination) field:

```
destination: {
    amount: 877,
    account: "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
},
```

but is there a way to do something similar with a subscription/plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to create the plan, customer and subscription on the connected account instead. This ensures that the owner of the account get their share of the funds. You would take the platform's share via an application fee. This is outlined [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions).

Another solution is to charge on the platform instead and after the fact, transfer funds to one (or multiple) connected accounts while linked the transfer to that billing cycle's charge. This approach is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#charging-transfer).

Comment: I may have to just transfer funds separately to the payable account, but I am hoping there is an automatic version. Essentially a recurring charge with destination (which doesn't seem too unreasonable, as recurring charges (plans/subscriptions) and charges with destinations are both supported separately). The payable accounts shouldn't have to do anything other than setup a payout account/schedule. Ideally, they have access to the payment information (charge/fee), but our agreement doesn't allow them to change any of that. They receive a set % of whatever price we set.

Comment: @TemporalWolf this is exactly what setting up the subscriptions on the connected account gives you and that's the road you should take. There is no `destination` equivalent for subscriptions yet otherwise.